# svn:ignore for a complicated directory structure

Tags: linux, svn, svnignore

i have a directory structure like this:

home/

```
- application/

- images/

- temporary/

     scripts/

     js/

     cache/

     uploads/
```

Now i want to keep my temporary directory and all the sub-directories like (scripts, js, cache, upload....) in the svn, but i want to svn:ignore all the content which is inside directories, so that every time i execute svn status -u, data from temporary directory won't list.

I am using linux. and using following commands:

svn propset svn:ignore "*" .

and then commit -m 'text'

i can see temporary directory listed when executing this command:

svn propget svn:ignore

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need this? Normally temporary directories should be created as part of your build process rather than being checked in.

Comment: Its the requirement, these directories must be in svn repo, but i need to ignore the content inside them.

Answer (score 1):

SVN Book **must be your best friend** for a long time.

Re-read **carefully** description of svn:ignore property in "Chapter 3. Advanced Topics" - "Properties" - [Subversion's Reserved Properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.ref) topic and detect 3 your mistakes

If you still will not be able to do it

> `svn:ignore`
>
> If present **on a directory**, the value is a list of
>   **unversioned file** patterns to be ignored by svn status and other
>   subcommands.

means:

- if you want to ignore files in `<somedir>` then svn:ignore **must be defined** for `<somedir>`, for every `<somedir>`, not just once *somewhere*
- files, which you want to see ignored, must not be versioned. Ingone will work only with externals files, **not** with **files already in repo**

Thus:

1. scripts/* + js/* + cache/* + uploads/* files **must** show status `?`, but parent directories - exist already in repo
2. `svn propset svn:ignore "*" .` **must** be executed not in outer space blindly but after `cd` to every parent dir, 4 times
3. Executed in unknown dir (`/home` ???) wrong `svn propset svn:ignore "*" .` **must** be found and undo'ed (`svn pd ...`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using svn version >= 1.7 you may consider the set-depth option, so that files will remain on the svn but you will not have them and not track them in your working copy.

svn update --set-depth='immediates' temporary

to revert use --set-depth='infinity'

and to check your working copies against svn server use both `svn list` and `svn info` commands.

Is that what you want ?